# Dropdown List Selected Item Always Set To Default Value when search filters

Tags: search, drop-down-menu, filter

http://www.zones.com/site/home/index.html?zone=business

When you go on to search an item say laptop it gives you the search result. Now try filtering the results by drop down **best match** is the default value, but when you select the **price:low to high** the results are filtered but the value of the drop down sets back to **best match** . how to avoid it may be with jquery or some script?

Please help .. Let me know if you need more info on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add the "selected" token in you option tag in the html

```
<option value="my value" selected>
```

How you do this depends on the language

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as I am having a limited programming knowledge It seems I will need to have a more detailed answer.